# Find out the number of Validators of a transaction if I have its transaction hash

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, mining

I want to find out how many validators have validated my transaction. My transaction hash is:

```
0x051430dc5cd84c44954e43b25f8709c9c1a1c634f384ec6dd7610f6f945732e1
```

Can anyone tell me how many validators validated my transaction in Ethereum blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

For ethereum there are many [Blockchain Explorers](https://www.etherchain.org) just type in your transaktion code and search. For your transaction it would be [this](https://www.etherchain.org/tx/051430dc5cd84c44954e43b25f8709c9c1a1c634f384ec6dd7610f6f945732e1) the block is what gets confirmed and with the block your transaction (since it is a part of that). Your Block had at the time of writing 9191 confirmations.